# How to write a node-webkit application with custom modules?

Tags: node.js, module, node-webkit

I am currently writing a node-webkit application. The application supports certain modules which lie in the module folder inside the application.

I would like to dynamically install and remove those modules from inside the application. For that i would need to dynamically write inside the application.nw file. Is there a best practice solution to my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not really a good idea. Just create a folder for app files and put downloaded packages there.

Comment: So saving the modules in for Example ~/.myapp/modules would be better?

Comment: yes. `.nw` is a zip file and is a part of a distribution. It is unpacked in some temp folder before app startup. Obviously you can add your modules to this temp folder, but you also will have to modify `.nw` if you want them to persist. Modifying binaries seems a bad idea to me. modules=user data